# Grayed out links: Lighthouse complains about insufficient contrast

Tags: html, google-chrome-devtools, accessibility, wai-aria, lighthouse

I want to show grayed-out placeholder text on my website for months where there is no newsletter.

[image]

Lighthouse (in Chrome Dev Tools) complains that these grayed-out items "do not have sufficient contrast ratio", but that is intentional.

Is there any way to annotate the elements to explain to Lighthouse (and any screen-readers) of my intention—i.e. that they should be ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any errors in Lighthouse can be safely ignored. There's nothing you need to do here.

As per Success Criteria 1.4.3 Contrast (Minimum) in WGAC 2.1, you are not required to maintain color contrast ratios for text or images that are part of an "inactive user interface component", which includes disabled text.

> **Success Criterion 1.4.3 Contrast (Minimum)**
>
> The visual presentation of text and images of text has a contrast ratio of at least 4.5:1, except for the following:
>
> ...
>
> **Incidental**: Text or images of text that are part of an inactive user interface component, that are pure decoration, that are not visible to anyone, or that are part of a picture that contains significant other visual content, have no contrast requirement.
>
> https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#contrast-minimum

This interpretation is supported by WebAIM, which states:

> WCAG 2.0 defines four types of "incidental" text that are not required to meet the contrast requirements.
>
> **Inactive**: An inactive element, like a disabled Submit button ( Submit ), is identified visually by its lower-contrast state...
>
> https://webaim.org/articles/contrast/#incidental

Comment: I found that adding `aria-disabled="true"` to the grayed-out labels stops Lighthouse reporting their low contrast as a problem.

Comment: @elevate - Be careful with using `aria-disabled` as it removes that element and all of its children from the accessibility tree. I'm not sure if that's really what you want to do. I don't see any major frameworks like jQuery UI or Material UI taking that approach.

Comment: It is perfectly fine in this case if he is applying it to each element, technically it won't do anything as his greyed out text should be just plain text and therefore inert. If they are links then that is a different accessibility issue but impossible to tell from an image.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I would like to happen in this case. Those elements are really only visual spacers, not needed in the accessibility tree. They're grayed-out text, not links.

Answer (score -1):

You can tell assistive technologies that the inactive strings are to be ignored, but that will not help users who have trouble reading those strings, either because their vision is less powerful than average or because they are viewing the UI in poor light. Don’t you want them to understand those strings? If you don’t, why are those strings displayed at all? In fact, what good do they do for any user? Wouldn’t the UI be easier to understand and navigate if they simply were not displayed?

Comment: They're visual spacers. When a month is missed, the layout of the months—their positions relative to each other—is maintained. I could make the gaps blank, but I think grayed-out month names is more intuitive for those who can see them. And for those that can't, or those that struggle to read them, I imagine they can guess what's going on.

Comment: I was only discussing some potential disadvantages of hard-to-read text. What in the comment seemed to be a judgment of any of the previous commenters?